# How to understand in perpetuity of +noun phrase?

Tags: word-meaning

For the sentence here:

> We intend this dedication to be an overt act of relinquishment in perpetuity of all present and future rights to this code under copyright law.

(from the [copyright of sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/copyright.html))

If the sentence is simply as

> We intend this dedication to be an overt act of relinquishment.

I understand it .

How to understand `in perpetuity of +noun phrase` here?

`in perpetuity of all present and future rights to this code under copyright law` maybe a sub-clause?
Or
`in perpetuity of all present and future rights to this code under copyright law` is a attribute ，if  so ,which is modified by it?

Comment: You're mis-parsing it slightly.  It's not "in perpetuity of X", it's two separate phrases: "in perpetuity" and "of X".  They're relinquishing X, in perpetuity.  It would have been much clearer if they had used commas or restructured the sentence, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can interpret it in two equivalent ways:

"relinquishment in perpetuity" (noun phrase)
"an overt act of relinquishment, in perpetuity, of all present and future rights" (parenthetical)

In both cases, "in perpetuity" is a property of "relinquishment," not of the following n.p.